# Inserting arrays into semantic's inference rules

Tags: math-mode, arrays, semantics

I want to typeset inference rules containing tables (or `array`s) in the premises. I'm using the `semantic` package, which sets the premises (and conclusion) in math mode, so I thought this might work:

```
\inference{\expr{axis} \in \left\{
    \begin{array}{l}
    \expr{child}\\ \expr{descendant}
    \end{array}
\right\} }{conclusion}
```

However, this gives me an error message I'm perplexed looking at:

```
ERROR: Missing \cr inserted.

--- TeX said ---
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.56 \right\} }
               {\expr{axis::node-test predicate*} : \<node-set>}
--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

I'm guessing that you meant to end an alignment here.
```

which is strange, because typesetting the premise alone in a math environment works fine:

```
$
\expr{axis} \in \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\expr{child}\\\expr{descendant}
\end{array}
\right\}
$
```

Could you shed some light on why am I getting the error message above and how to get rid of it?

PS: `\expr{}` is basically `\texttt{}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can "protect" the `array` from the `\inference` construction by using braces:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{semantic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/semantic
\newcommand{\expr}{\texttt}
\begin{document}
\inference{\expr{axis} \in \left\{
    {\begin{array}{l}
    \expr{child}\\ \expr{descendant}
    \end{array}}
\right\} }{conclusion}
\end{document}​
```

The reason for this being a problem is because, in a nested way, the `\inference` macro processes the premises (first argument) expecting a `\\`; actually, it expects `<something>\\<something>\end`, and the `\\` in your `array` construction conflicts with this definition.

In this instance, you could also replace `\\` with `\cr` to remove the conflict usage.